# Soundcloud not resizing correctly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float, soundcloud

Trying out Soundcloud for a site.  I resized the iframe to fit the space - this worked seamlessly in Chrome/FF/Safari.

On IE however it's not resizing but truncating the viewable space.

For example:

[The way it's supposed to look:](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/4135/a1e99371c7c441e8b81f6ba.png)
[image]

[IE's interpretation (can't really see or click play button):](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/7923/c0c000703a8743039cd7bde.png)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="rightnav_below">
    <iframe width="100%" height="180" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http...&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=ff7700"></iframe>
</div><!-- end .rightnav_below -->
```

CSS:

```
#wrap #content #rightnav_wrapper .rightnav_below {display: block; text-align: left; margin-top: 20px;  background: #ccc; border-color:#fc663d;}

#wrap #content #rightnav_wrapper  .rightnav_below iframe{float: none;  height: 180px; width: 180px; vertical-align: top; }
```

Also, getting an error in IE when I do hit that tiny play portion:

Webpage error details

```
Message: 'nodeName' is null or not an object
Line: 3
Char: 99080
Code: 0
URI: http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=...http...&auto_play=false&show_artwork=true&color=ff7700
```

Any ideas what's going on?  Thanks!

Comment: It's not just you. We have the same problem on our band website. It's an issue with the soundcloud widget.

Comment: Damn - no word on a time frame from them?  Or a work around?

Comment: Had a thought this morning - I keep seeing references to the "old flash player".  If I had that appear for IE then that would solve the problem I think.  Thoughts?

Comment: To be honest i can't be bothered spending calories on this. I'm sure they realise the problem, and there's nothing I can do about it to fix it.